# Класс для работы с сетью

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Есть вот такой код

```
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class FetchJson {
    public String getJsonString(String url) throws IOException{
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String result = response.body().string();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Как мне передать в метод getJsonString метод, который нужно вызвать и передать результат запроса по завершению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать интерфейс:

```
interface MyCallback {

    void call(String result);
}
```

Передавать его в качестве параметра:

```
public void getJsonString(String url, MyCallback callback) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String result = response.body().string();

    callback.call(result);
}
```

При вызове реализовывать метод интерфейса:

```
FetchJson fetchJson = new FetchJson();
try {
    fetchJson.getJsonString("http://example.com", new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(String result) {
            // тут получаем наш результат
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // etc
}
```